# Unable to pass an address of array of type char *[2] to function taking char ***

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

My XCode (default compiler should be clang?) shows me on this code a warning:

`Incompatible pointer types passing 'char *(*)[2]' to parameter of type 'char ***'` (when calling func)

```
void func (char ***arrayref, register size_t size) {
    /// ...
}

int main()
{
    char *array[2] = {"string", "value"};
    func(&array, 2);
}
```

while this code is no problem (=no warning):

```
void func (char **arrayref, register size_t size) {
    /// ...
}

int main()
{
    char *array[2] = {"string", "value"};
    func(array, 2);
}
```

While this removes the warning

```
func((char***)&array, 2);
```

**I still don't know why the first emits a warning, while the latter doesn't.**

Also, when the first is a problem, I'd also expect that the first emits a warning like:

`Incompatible pointer types passing 'char *[2]' to parameter of type 'char **'`

Comment: The error is pretty clear: `char *[10]` and `char **` are two different things.

Comment: Because the cast says `I know what I'm doing don't warn me`

Comment: @LihO yes. But why does the second code NOT emit a warning then?

Comment: @user814064 that was not my question. I just write that with the cast to show that I'm aware of the workaround...

Comment: I don't understand your question. This cast's only function is to remove the warning.

Comment: @user814064 the question is: why does the first code emit a warning, while the second doesn't?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned (please correct me if I'm wrong), C compilers don't distinguish between `char**` and `char*[]`. Both are 2-dimensional pointers.

Comment: @Mauren okay. And why does the compiler then distinguish somehow between `char***` and `char**[]`?

Comment: @bwoebi trying to figure out as well.

Comment: Had a problem understanding your question -- sorry. Posted an answer that shows how to change the array by passing a pointer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Time for a brief refresher on array semantics.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.

The expression `array` in your code has type "2-element array of `char *`", or `char *[2]`.  When you pass it as an argument to `func`, as in

```
func( array, 2 );
```

the expression is converted to an expression of type "pointer to `char *`", or `char **`, which is the type your function is expecting, and the value of the expression is the address of the first element: `array == &array[0]`.  This is why you don't get the warning for the second code snippet.

In the first snippet, the array is an operand of the unary `&` operator, so the conversion to a pointer type doesn't happen; instead, the type of the expression is "pointer to *2-element array of* `char *`", or `char *(*)[2]`, which is not compatible with `char **`.  The address *value* is the same (the address of the first element of the array is the same as the address of the array itself), but the types don't match, hence the warning.

So why does this matter?  A pointer is just an address, and all address are the same, right?  Well, no.  A pointer is an *abstraction* of an address, with associated type semantics.  Pointers to different types don't have to have the same size or representation, and pointer arithmetic depends on the type of the pointed-to type.

For example, if I declare a pointer as `char **p;`, then the expression `p++` will advance the pointer to point to the next object of type `char *`, or `sizeof (char *)` bytes from the current address.  If `p` is declared as `char *(*p)[2]`, however, the expression `p++` will advance `p` to point to the next *two-element array* of `char *`, which is 2 * `sizeof (char *)` bytes from the current address.

Comment: Had to read it 3 times… Thank you. (I think this is something a lot of people misunderstand…)

Comment: I *know* a lot of people misunderstand this, because pointer and array semantics are not intuitive and almost universally taught badly, without any [historical background](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html) to give it context. It's a good thing I don't teach C, because fully half the semester would be spent just going over types.

Comment: I am over the half with reading… will continue tomorrow. But it is ___very___ informative. Thank you. (I use the words "thank" and "you" too often in combination…)

Comment: Great answer! Still tough to wrap one's head around.

Answer (score 6):

```
char *array[2] = {"string", "value"};
```

is an array with 2 elements of `char *`.

Using `array` as an address results to a pointer to the first element, i. e. of type `char **`.

Using `&array` results to a pointer to the same place, but of type `char *(*)[2]` (not sure if the spelling is right).

This is not the same as a `char ***` - the representation in memory is completely different.

To be more verbose,

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ array[0] + array[1] +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
```

this is the array.

```
char ** p1 = array; // is a pointer to the first element, which in turn is a pointer.
char *(*p2)[2] = &array; // is a pointer to the whole array. Same address, but different type, i. e. sizeof(*p1) != sizeof(*p2) and other differences.

char ***p3 = &p1; // Now, p1 is a different pointer variable which has an address itself which has type `char ***`.
```

Comment: Now this is confusing me: How would I then make a pointer to array (e.g. to the pointer pointing to the first element)?

Comment: @bwoebi A pointer to the first element, which is a `char *`, would be a `char **`. It is `&array[0]` and can be abbreviated to `array`, as an array name, in most cases, degrades into a pointer to its first element.

Comment: e.g. I want to change the array the variable `array` points to in the function `func`.

Comment: The variable `array` does not *point* to an array, it `is` an array. If you really have a `char ***` parameter, you'll have to supply the address of an intermediate variable (such as `p3` in my example). Think of `array` as a constant value such as `4` or `71`, whose address you cannot change as well.

Comment: Okay, that describes it better. Didn't know that such arrays would be constant. Confusing C.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of how to do what you want and change what array points to:

```
char *array2[] = {"string", "NewValue"};

void func0 (char **arrayref, register size_t size) {
    puts(arrayref[1]);
}

void func1 (char ***arrayref, register size_t size) {
    puts(arrayref[0][1]);
    *arrayref= (char **) array2;

}

int main()
{
    char *array[] = {"string", "value"};
    char **foo = array;
    func0(foo, 2);
    func1(&foo,2);
    func0(foo, 2);
}
```

Comment: That is basically the same than @glglgl wrote, but with a more self-explaining code example. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of type `char *[2]` i.e. array of 2 pointers to `char`. It is an array of fixed size with automatic storage duration. The only thing that your function can do with this kind of array is to either use its elements or to change them (it can not resize it or deallocate it... therefore it makes no sense to try to make it possible to change the array itself ~> in other words: you don't really need a pointer to this kind of array).

Here's a simple example:

```
void func (char *arrayref[2]) {
    printf("%s", arrayref[1]);
    arrayref[1] = "new value";
}

int main() {    {
    char *array[2] = {"string", "value"};
    func(array);
    printf(" -> %s", array[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

or alternatively changing `func` to take an array of unspecified size making it usable with `char *[X]` for any `X`, not just `2` (in that case it makes sense already to pass the array's size):

```
void func (char *arrayref[], size_t size) {
    if (size > 1) {
        printf("%s", arrayref[1]);
        arrayref[1] = "new value";
    }
}
```

with one way or other, this program would output `value -> new value`.

If you need your function to be able to resize this array or affect *the array itself* in some other way, you should consider using dynamically-allocated array and passing in form of `char**`.